# UITableView inside UITableViewCell - unexpected results

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

1. This is how my `cell` with `tableView` looks like. Everything is fine when it is loaded.

[image]

2. This is how I configure my custom cell:

   ```
   //this method is inside `BWPendingTableViewCell`
   func configureCellWithStudent(student: BWCoreDataStudent) {

       notifications = Array(student.notifications).filter({ $0.type == "purchase_reward" }).sort({ $0.id < $1.id })

       tableView.delegate = self
       tableView.dataSource = self
       tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
       tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0

       nameLabel.text = student.firstName
       avatarImageView.setImageWithUrl(student.avatarStringURL)
   }
   ```
3. Within nested `tableView`'s `cell` there is a button. When it is tapped all it does is to call delegate method like this:

   ```
   //this method is inside `BWPendingTableViewCell`
   func notificationTableViewCellDidSelectConfirmButton(cell: BWNotificationTableViewCell, notification: BWCoreDataNotification) {

       if let indexPath = notifications.indexOf(notification) {
           notifications.removeAtIndex(indexPath)
       }

       tableView.reloadData()

       MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock { context in
           notification.MR_deleteEntityInContext(context)
       }
   }
   ```
4. The logic seems to be very fine. But sth is wrong when I start to tapping that buttons:

[image]
[image]

Everything is wrong. Within **Alice** cell there are notifications related to **Bob**. It happens once I tap some button. Why?

How do I present notification cell?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(BWNotificationPurchaseRewardCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BWNotificationTableViewCell
    cell.configureCellWithNotification(notifications[indexPath.row])
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

Comment: whats the problem ???? seems like you get 3 rows instead 4 ... right???  or image is incorrect ...

Comment: But pay attention about student's name: within `Alice` there are rows with `Bob`... i do not know why.

Comment: had you print your data when you click on row ...

Comment: Yes, everthing seems fine when line with `MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock` is commented out. It always remove proper cells, and display apriopriate result. But why it influence on result when MagicalRecord works? I just remove this from the persistent store.

Comment: Please show how you implement cellForRowAtIndexPath and how you define the buttonAction.

Comment: What table do you mean? Nested or not?

Comment: I meant how you implement the tableView.dataSource

Comment: But there are two tables. The big one, and the nested one inside every cell of the big one. Which one you mesn?

Comment: The one presenting notification as cell.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110698/discussion-between-dichen-and-bartlomiej-semanczyk).